# Reverse engineering GCN binary (ELF) in C#, but not an expert on elf or elf conventions. Do some of these sections/section names look familiar?

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, elf

My first exposure to the ELF format binary began less than 2 weeks ago; please excuse the crudeness of my grasp of them (and of course, correction of any misconceptions I display here would be welcome).

The story so far: I have some GCN binaries which I am trying to fully reverse engineer so that I might be able to generate my own with a higher degree of control (i.e. limiting the number of intermediate steps executed by code not my own and not entirely within my understanding).  What I've found from some resources online and my own delving is that each binary contains two ELF structures; the first is fairly small, containing three sections (no program headers) named "", ".shstrtab", and ".ddiPipelineHeader".

The ".ddiPipelineHeader" section size is 48 bytes, with the byte 0 being a 1, and bytes 16-19 containing what appears to be a 32bit integer that corresponds to the number of bytes in the binary from the start of the second ELF structure.  All the other bytes in this section are 0.  A google search of ".ddiPipelineHeader" returned exactly 1 result which I didn't find useful.  Before I run off all half-cocked into dangerous, crashy GPU experimentation-land, does this section's structure sound at all familiar?  Is there possibly an explanation of what each byte would do (e.g. bytes 4-15 are 0 padding, etc. etc.)?

I also have all the sections contained in the second ELF to ask about, but I figure I'll be able to delve more deeply into those with a better foundation gleaned here, so I'll hold off on that part for now.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: As a convention, I always leave extra cookies and milk, enough for santa to take back.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following O_o

Comment: Cultural divide: https://www.google.com/search?q=santa+and+his+elves&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_16OUgLrNAhXDHB4KHeVOAVYQ_AUICCgB&biw=1295&bih=671

Comment: No, I get that part, I'm just having trouble making the connection between the joke my question here.  I was wondering if I'd broken an unwritten rule or something.

Comment: You see, ELF is the singular of Elves.  Santa has Elves.  Elves like cookies.  Leaving extra cookies, santa gets his fill and can bring them back to his Elves, making them happy.

Comment: Oh duh.  For some reason I wasn't making the ELF-elf connection.  I've been maybe a little too focused on this project. :)